# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.getWidth() what problem?

Tags: java, android, crash

I don't know how to solve it

logcat:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.getWidth()' on a null object reference
at com.example.cashapp.Fragments.HomeFragment.shineStart(HomeFragment.java:406)
at com.example.cashapp.Fragments.HomeFragment.access$000(HomeFragment.java:78)
at com.example.cashapp.Fragments.HomeFragment$1$1.run(HomeFragment.java:134)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

code:
Java:

```
        layout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout);
        Shine = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.shine);

        ScheduledExecutorService executorService =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        shineStart();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 3,3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    private void shineStart() {

        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                0,
                layout.getWidth()+Shine.getWidth(),0,0);
        animation.setDuration(550);
        animation.setFillAfter(false);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        Shine.startAnimation(animation);
    }
        layout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout);
        Shine = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.shine);

        ScheduledExecutorService executorService =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        shineStart();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 3,3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);x
```

XML:

```
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout"
                    android:layout_width="126dp"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/header"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/shine"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="-50dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/shine_drawable"
                        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

what exactly is going on and how to solve it
i really dont know what is the error i try some things, again this error show
any suggestions exactly?

Comment: Which problem? `NullPointerException`

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.getWidth()

Comment: To be specific, this is caused by your code calling `getWidth()` on what's essentially a `null` value at runtime, so it throws that exception. You should be able to fix it by ensuring that `layout` is actually **set** to a value _before_ you then call `getWidth` on it

Comment: Either `layout` is `null` or `Shine` is `null`. Note that `Shine` is likely to have other problems, as you have it as a child of `layout` but lack constraints to say where `Shine` should appear within `layout`.

Comment: … on a null object reference. You stopped reading the error message just at the point where it got interesting.